# Getting unknown characters while decoding string in c#

Tags: c#, xml, encoding, special-characters, decoding

I am working on a project where I am submitting my form data as xml and storing it in xml form to my db.

While decoding the xml data in c# I am getting unknown characters. Actually I am saving spanish text for eg  " Introduzca texto aquí ".

So in xml I get this 'í' character as %ED and while decoding it using `HttpUtility.UrlDecode(formData)` I am getting � instead of í.

XML Data before decoding

```
%3CArrayOfDiary%3E%3CDiary%3E%3CDate%3E03042015%3C/Date%3E%3CSituation%3EIntroduzca%20texto%20aqu%ED%3C/Situation%3E%3CSensation%3EIntroduzca%20texto%20aqu%ED%3C/Sensation%3E%3CConcern%3EIntroduzca%20texto%20aqu%ED%3C/Concern%3E%3CBeliefRating%3E0%3C/BeliefRating%3E%3CAnxietyRating%3E0%3C/AnxietyRating%3E%3C/Diary%3E%0A%20%20%3CArrayOfDiary%3E
```

Data after decoding

```
<ArrayOfDiary><Diary><Date>03042015</Date><Situation>Introduzca texto aqu�</Situation><Sensation>Introduzca texto aqu�</Sensation><Concern>Introduzca texto aqu�</Concern><BeliefRating>0</BeliefRating><AnxietyRating>0</AnxietyRating></Diary>
<Diary>
<Date>03042015</Date>
<Situation> Introduzca texto aqu�</Situation>
<Sensation> Introduzca texto aqu�</Sensation>
<Concern> Introduzca texto aqu�</Concern>
<BeliefRating>0</BeliefRating>
<AnxietyRating>0</AnxietyRating>
</Diary>
</ArrayOfDiary>
```

Please help me. Thanks

Comment: You should place `N` before the spanish language characters in your c# code  for example `N'español'`

Comment: you mean to say my text should be "Introduzca texto aquNí ",but how it will help in decoding,what's the purpose of placing N,please explain

Comment: I mean this `N'Introduzca texto aquí'` 
check this link 
http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/239530

Comment: edit your question and add your c# code  regarding encoding/decoding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing where the data is coming from, I assume that it has been created with an encoding of ISO-8859-1.

You can get around the problem by using the appropriate Encoding in UrlDecode:

```
Option Infer On
' ....
Dim s = "%3CArrayOfDiary%3E%3CDiary%3E%3CDate%3E03042015%3C/Date%3E%3CSituation%3EIntroduzca%20texto%20aqu%ED%3C/Situation%3E%3CSensation%3EIntroduzca%20texto%20aqu%ED%3C/Sensation%3E%3CConcern%3EIntroduzca%20texto%20aqu%ED%3C/Concern%3E%3CBeliefRating%3E0%3C/BeliefRating%3E%3CAnxietyRating%3E0%3C/AnxietyRating%3E%3C/Diary%3E%0A%20%20%3CArrayOfDiary%3E"
Dim enc = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")
Dim txt = Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(s, enc)
```

To avoid that hassle, you could use `<meta charset="utf-8" />` in the `<head>` section of the web page. You can still have `<html lang="es">` if you want to indicate that the page is in Spanish.

Answer (score 0):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246590.aspx

Check out this page it should help you, it sounds like you may not have the right LIP

Comment: But If I save spanish data directly I am able to view it correctly while decoding from xml I am getting this unknown character